# How to set number of pages to print using UIPrintInteractionController.print in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using the `UIPrintInteractionController` to print a html from a `UIWebView` directly to an AirPrint printer. I would like to tell the `UIPrinter` that only the first page should be printed. How can I do this?

Here is my code which prints all pages:

```
let printer = UIPrinter(url: myURL)
let printerController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
printInfo.jobName = "My print job name"
printInfo.outputType = .general
printerController.printInfo = printInfo

let printPageRenderer = MyCustomPageRenderer()
printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(myWebView.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0)

printerController.printPageRenderer = printPageRenderer
printerController.print(to: printer!) { (printerController, success, error) in
 
}
```

The code should be compatible with iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is **`numberOfPages`** property in **`UIPrintPageRenderer`** that you can override. Or you may just set the **`UIPrintInteractionController`** property **`showsPageRange`** to **true**.

For more reference please use see this link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintpagerenderer/1621631-numberofpages

Comment: Yes, but with the print method I avoid the dialog, so the property is useless in this case, right?